# Can I merge/delete these partitions without breaking everything?

Tags: partitioning

I'm curious, which of these partitions can I safely merge?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Um, which ones are you talking about?

Comment: I'm sorry I'm trying to figure out why it won't let me embed images into my question

Comment: You don't enough rep to enable it. Hopefully my edit will go through and you will see it.

Comment: Gotcha, well I just linked them instead

Comment: Just wait, my edit still needs to be accepted.

Comment: @TonyLancer - I approved it. Just need one more person to approve as well.

Comment: There you go, @TonyLancer

Comment: You want to merge sda and sdb?

Comment: @TonyLancer - That's not even possible without JBOD...

Comment: Can I? I'm new to Linux so I'm not even really sure what sdb is/does. I was more asking which partitions in each I could merge but if I can put sdb into sda that'd be even better

Comment: @StevenBrailsford - let me write an answer for you

Comment: As Android Dev is writing an answer for you, let me explain in simple terms. No. There are two different "houses"(if you will) that live on the same island, but quite far away from one another.

Comment: @StevenBrailsford Just curious, those are two physical HDDs, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, unlike Windows with uses letters such as `C:\` to identify disks, Linux sees them as block devices, such as `/dev/sda` and `/dev/sdb`. For example, `/dev/sda1` would be the first partition on your first disk, and `/dev/sdb4` would be the fourth partition on your second disk.

In your case, I can see that you actually have **two** HDDs/SSDs. As in, two physically separate pieces of hardware. You **cannot** merge two physical disks, unless you do some advanced stuff using RAID and/or JBOD.

Now, on your first disk, `/dev/sda`, you have the `EFI` partition, (the bootloader), you have your main Linux partition (where all of your data is stored), and you have your `swap` partition, which is equivalent to Windows's "page file". (An area used as virtual RAM if you run out of physical RAM). None of those partitions can be merged. Period.

About your second disk; I'm a bit confused as to why you have two `EFI` partitions on it... But, you could *potentially* be able to merge `/dev/sdb2`, `/dev/sdb4`, and `/dev/sdb6`, but without knowing what's on those partitions, I don't know if it would be safe to merge them.

Comment: In short: those aren't two partitions you're asking to merge, they're two separate hard drives.

Comment: What's curious, though is that I don't have two separate drives, so I'm confused why sdb even exists...

Answer (score 0):

**If your goal is to eliminate the sdb 22GiB drive**, you can either move some of the data (*it appears you have very little data there*) from sdb to sda. This would be very easy if you have a /home directory on /sda2. Just move data from /sdb2, /sdb4, and /sdb6 partitions to the /home directory on /sda2. Then you'll need to edit /etc/fstab.

If you don't have /home directory on sda2, you can use `gparted` on a Ubuntu Live DVD to shrink /sda2, create a new /home partition /sda4, and then move data from the /sdb2, /sdb4, and sdb6 partitions to the new /sda4 partition on sda. Then you'll need to edit /etc/fstab.

Or, instead of creating /sda4, you could shrink /sda2, and move entire partitions, using copy/paste in gparted, from sdb to sda. Again, you'll need to edit /etc/fstab.

I'm making some assumptions, based on little data. If you have questions about any of this, please ask. Cheers, Al

Comment: I'm just not sure why there's even an sdb drive, I don't have two drives so I'm confused

Comment: Do you have a USB flash card inserted? You've got a sdb drive somewhere! Cheers, Al